# .reduce returning concat instead of total sum

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, concatenation, reduce

Can someone explain to me the differences between these examples please?

Here's the original code.

```
const items = [
    { name: "Bike", price: 100 },
    { name: "TV", price: 200 },
    { name: "Album", price: 10 },
    { name: "Book", price: 5 },
    { name: "Phone", price: 500 },
    { name: "Computer", price: 1000 },
    { name: "Keyboard", price: 25 },
];

const total = items.reduce((total, amount) => {
    return total + amount.price;
});

console.log("total", total);
```

above returns `total [object Object]200105500100025` <- what is this [object Object] and also why is the result 200105500100025 instead of 1840?

```
const total = items.reduce((total, amount) => {
    return total + amount.price;
}, 0);
```

this code returns `total 1840` which is what I was looking for but why does having ,0); at the end change this result? Does it change the price values to 'numbers' instead of an 'object' or 'string' like the above?

I noticed that some tutorails on YouTube say that because it's an arrow function I don't need to type 'return' and make the code look like:

```
const total = items.reduce((total, amount) => {total + amount.price}, 0);
```

But this returns me a result of `total undefined`
What's the difference between having `return` and not having it?

Comment: Reading the documentation for [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and for [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) should have helped you resolve both of these issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The issue with `[object Object]` is, as you noticed yourself, the missing `, 0`.

   This is because you can use `.reduce` in two ways: With a starting value, and without. Without a starting value, the first call to your callback will have the *first two elements* as arguments, so the first element is used as starting value and the first call is skipped. This makes sense in some cases such as when you do `[1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b)` where `1 + 2` is a valid first operation, but it doesn't make sense in your case where you actually access a *property* of each element.

   In your case, that means that the first call will have `{ name: "Bike", price: 100 }` as `total` and `{ name: "TV", price: 200 }` as `amount`. You are then doing `{ name: "Bike", price: 100 } + 200` which will be interpreted as string concatenation and turn the first object into `[object Object]`, resulting in `[object Object]200`. From then on, the remaining prices are also concatenated (because the intermediate value is now a string), resulting in `[object Object]200105500100025` at the end.

   With the `, 0`, you specify `0` as starting value. In that case, the first call to your callback function will have `0` as `total` and `{ name: "Bike", price: 100 }` as `amount`, which makes a lot more sense. You then do `0 + 100`, correctly resulting in the number `100`, and so on.
2. The problem with `undefined` is that when you are writing `(total, amount) => { total + amount.price }` instead of `(total, amount) => total + amount.price` you are not returning anything.

   `(args) => xyz` is a shorthand for `(args) => { return xyz }`. As soon as you add the `{ }`, you are no longer using the shorthand and hence you have to take care of `return`ing manually. Writing just `{ xyz }` would evaluate `xyz` but not return anything, as you saw it happening here. This makes more sense if you think about that the main use case is a block with several statements inside the braces, probably spanning multiple lines, and the `return` statement could then be at any place that you want inside of that block.

Comment: Wow.. I usually don't understand people's answers so I have to read it over and over again to be able to understand but you made it so easy by explaining it in layman's term.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you don't include an initial value as the second argument for `.reduce()`, the accumulator (ie: `number`) for the reduce callback starts off as the *first* value in your array, and the element (ie: `amount`) begins at the second element in your array.

In your case, this means that the `number` is initially:

```
{ name: "Bike", price: 100 }
```

which you then add with `amount.price`. As you're adding an object with a number, the object's `.toString()` method is called resulting in `[object Object]`. This means your accumulator is now a *string*, so any further additions are really concatenation operations with a string. When you include an initial value though, the accumulator (`number`) starts off as `0`, and the element (`amount`) starts off as the first object. This means you when you do `total + amount.price` you're adding a number with a number, resulting in the correct value.

> I noticed that some tutorails on YouTube say that because it's an
> arrow function I don't need to type 'return'

When using arrow functions, you don't have to include a function body (ie: `{}`). When you don't include the body, the return is implicit (ie: not needed), and it will automatically return the expression to the right of the `=>`. However, when you have a body, you need to include an explicit return, as the body can include *many* statements within it. When you don't return from a function body your function will return nothing, which is why you're getting `undefined`. An example of it working without the body would be to use:

```
const total = items.reduce((total, amount) => total + amount.price, 0);
```